# Drag and drop from a table

Tags: jquery, html-table, drag-and-drop

I'm using drag and drop of elements inside a table.
But I need also to drag the elements out of the table, and drop them over a "bin icon" in order to erase them.

The drag&drop works well in the table, but when I want to drag out of the table, they are hidden (they go under the other elements of my page). I have tried the z-index and position properties, without sucess.

Does anybody have an idea ?

I speak about these part of html :

```
<div id="calendar">
  <div class="ui-widget wc-container">
    <div class="ui-widget-header wc-toolbar">
      <div class="ui-widget-content wc-header">
        <div class="wc-scrollable-grid" style="height: 416px;">
          <table class="wc-time-slots">
            <tbody>
              <tr class="wc-grid-row-timeslot">
              <tr class="wc-grid-row-oddeven">
              <tr class="wc-grid-row-events">
```

The elements are in wc-grid-row-events and I want to drop them on wc-header

My javascript is :

```
        $calEvent.draggable({
            containment: '#Calendrier', //pour permettre le drag des saisies jusqu'à l'icône corbeille
            revert: 'invalid',
            opacity: 0.5,
            start: function (event, ui) {
                var $calEvent = ui.draggable || ui.helper;
                options.eventDrag(calEvent, $calEvent);
                ui.helper.css("z-index", "10");
                ui.helper.css("position", "absolute");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could you show us a live example of your code?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to suggest without a sample code. But let's say you are using draggable facility.

```
$("#draggableid").draggable({ containment: "document" });
```

this should work in your case. by default the containment is parent which in your case is table. but if you give containment as document. It would be possible to drag the window in entire document.

You should not use the tr as your draggable element. if you want rows to be draggable use "div" "ul" and "li" tags. As they will not be the part of the table you can easily drag them anywhere.

refer source at : http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [jQuery UI Draggable?](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)
If so, i think the **`appendTo`** option is interesting in your case:

> The element passed to or selected by the appendTo option will be used as the draggable helper's container during dragging. By default, the helper is appended to the same container as the draggable.

For example:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ appendTo: "body" });
```

Comment: Yes I'm using jQuery ui draggable. But the appendTo option does not change anything

Comment: @Elodie which elements are you dragging exactly?

Comment: I'm dragging an event which is a div : <div class="wc-cal-event ui-corner-all ui-resizable ui-draggable" style="line-height: 15px; font-size: 13px; top: 0px; height: 160px; display: block;">